# How to remove GTK entry (textbox) border?

Tags: css, c, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

I want there to be no border at all. I tried the following code:

```
     GtkCssProvider *provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data (GTK_CSS_PROVIDER (provider), 
"entry, .entry, GtkEntry { border-width:0px ; }", 
-1, NULL); 

GdkDisplay *display = gdk_display_get_default ();
GdkScreen *screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen (display);
gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen (screen, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER     
         (provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
```

Comment: Not sure if it must be by using css but what a about the [*has-frame*](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntry.html#GtkEntry--has-frame) property of GtkEntry?

Comment: @JoséFonte I tried that. border:none was the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it with `entry { border:none }`